# SendGrid Configuration with React and Node/express Server

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, sendgrid

As my title would suggest I am attempting to implement Sendgrid in my react project.  I am using a node backend with an express server and react-router on the front-end.  A similar question was asked on another thread but did not know if having a react-router in place complicated the process.  Here is my code:

Front-end

```
onFormSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (!this.state.name || !this.state.email || !this.state.message) {
        this.setState(() => ({ error: 'Please fill out all the above fields!' }));
    } else {
        this.setState(() => ({ error: '' }));

        fetch('/contact', {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
              'Accept': 'application/json',
              'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({
              name: this.state.name,
              email: this.state.email,
              message: this.state.message
            })
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            console.error(error);
          });
    }

}
```

Back-end (server setup)

```
const path = require('path');
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const publicPath = path.join(__dirname, '../public');
const port = process.env.PORT || 8080;
const sgMail = require('@sendgrid/mail');

app.use(express.static(publicPath));

app.get('*', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.join(publicPath, 'index.html'));
});

app.post('/contact', (req, res) => {

sgMail.setApiKey(process.env.SENDGRID_API_KEY);
  const msg = {
     to: 'email',
     from: 'email',
     subject: 'New Message From Portfolio',
     text: 'test',
     html: '<strong>and easy to do anywhere, even with 
            Node.js</strong>',
  };
  sgMail.send(msg);
})

app.listen(port, () => {
 console.log('Server is running');
 });
```

When I run this code I am getting a 404 "/contact" not found. Conceptually I think I am in the right place but was curious why my front end is not recognizing this route. I am fetching from the route /contact and have the corresponding express post on my server.

Comment: not totally sure, but I think you may need to swap the order of your routes. I think your catch all route should be the last one defined.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback!  I changed the order ironically right before you commented, but unfortunately still have the same error.

Comment: are the backend and frontend running on different ports?

Comment: Alright so I am working with webpack for the first time... I had a development server running in my console... instead I ran my node server (production) and the route was identified.  In the network dev tools the post is 'pending'... probably a compatibility issue with the data? Spits out an error 4 minutes later "net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE"

Comment: Nah, thats coming from the fact you are not actually responding from the route handler.  You are only calling `sgMail.send(msg);`, you would also need some sort of response.

Comment: I am not sure I completely follow... with the current code my response would be running the sendgrid code with the data sent to the server.... or are you talking more along the lines of a response as in a promise after the code is ran.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/184785/discussion-between-chaim-friedman-and-d-man).

Comment: Do you see in this code why my console.log would be coming back as undefined?

Comment: Are you using body parser?